How to properly limit motor overspeed during regenerative torque
I are facing a potential issue and need some help with possible solutions.
How to stop motor from over-speeding during a regenerative load, once maximum torque current limit is hit and the system's ability to absorb energy is challenged?
During regenerative torque, the motor which now acts as a generator feeds current back to the DC bus capacitor bank which increases the bus voltage.
To keep the dc bus voltage in check, we have a brake resistor/brake chopper through which the excess energy is dissipated.
Consider the following situation:

The motor is rotating in positive direction at a fixed speed in speed control mode. Speed control mode means that the controller has to maintain constant speed, irrespective of the load.
Maximum possible current in the system is +-50Amps.[Limited by Motor and hardware specifications].
Inside the Software(which uses an FOC controller), maximum quadrature current limit is set to +- 40 Amps.

If there is a load to the motor which applies a regenerative torque(-ve torque) , The torque is so much that there occurs a case where the software's current limit is hit(-30 Amps), the motor speed will now start to increase!!(as the excessive regenerative load is still present!!)
One solution to this that I have come up with is that can we instruct the brake chopper(Which would already have started working as the dc bus would have started increasing) to increase its duty cycle even more..What I mean by this is if the existing brake chopper's duty cycle is 15%, now we increase it to 2x or 3x times the existing value?
One more issue that I have observed: The motor currents are measured on the midpoints of the inverter bridge legs via shunt resistors and we also have comparators which monitor the currents flowing through these shunts and trigger an over-current fault if the current crosses +- 50 Amps.
During regenerative torque and software's current limit is hit(-30 Amps), sometimes this fault is triggered during sudden high regenerative torque transients.
Does this mean that the braking effort during these transients is not enough?

There is no problem, you simply control the motor current (torque) at -30A or what ever you need. The speed matters if you turn off PWM - then you get BEMF charging your capacitors and popping them if you don't discharge soon enough. Having that said, you also need to make sure current can flow back to battery. Otherwise sooner or later you'll get your capacitors overcharged.
